# How Can I add another Condition That will Detect that the Path is Missing

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2017

I'am trying to create a watchdog app for some program on our company. I can already start the program if it was closed but my last problem is how can the watchdog detect if the program it monitor is missing. I would like to add another condition in which if the Program is not found(Firefox for example) it will restart the system. Thank You

```
Module Module1

Public Sub Main()
    Application.Run(New Watchdog)
End Sub

End Module
```

---

```
Public Class Watchdog
Inherits ApplicationContext

Private AppToWatch As String
Private FullPath As String = "C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\firefox1.exe"

Private WithEvents P As Process

Public Sub New()
    AppToWatch = System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(FullPath)
    Dim PS() As Process = Process.GetProcessesByName(AppToWatch)
    If PS.Length = 0 Then
        StartIt()


    Else
        P = PS(0)
        P.EnableRaisingEvents = True

    End If
End Sub

Private Sub P_Exited(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles P.Exited
    StartIt()
End Sub

Private Sub StartIt()
    P = Process.Start(FullPath)
    P.EnableRaisingEvents = True
End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: So, you searched the web for information on how to find out whether a file exists and couldn't find anything, or you didn't bother to search at all?

Comment: I did but I don't know where to put the condition.

Comment: It's your logic.  You must know when, within that logic, you want to determine whether the file exists or not.  That would be where you put the check.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way to keep checking if the app is running is to check your processes every 5 minutes or whatever interval you want using a timer, and if you don't find it then you can call "StartIt()", make sure you enable that timer too..

Comment: Thank you for this sir. It gave me an idea on what should I do . Thanks

Comment: sure no problem